# Is it normal for a RegEx to give more than one matching for a single match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am sorry if the question title is a bit confusing, but here I will elaborate my confusion in detail.

I want to use regular expression to match apple, orange, mango, apple[(can have any number or empty)], orange[(can have any number or empty)]. (Notice mango will NOT have []). Here are some of the valid examples:

1. apple MATCHED
2. orange MATCHED
3. apple[] MATCHED
4. orange[] MATCHED
5. apple[15] MATCHED
6. apple[05] NOT MATCHED(because a number should not start with 0)
7. mango[] NOT MATCHED(because mango can't have [])

Here is the regular expression I come up with:

```
/^(mango|(apple|orange)(\[[1-9][0-9]*\])?)$
```

This regular expression works, but usually it gives more than 1 matching group. For example `apple[15]` will give
1. `apple[15]`
2. `apple[15]`
3. `[15]`

Actually the behavior is normal as I have many `()` which creates many groups, but I wonder if I am using the right way to construct this regular expression? Because it just gives too many results for a single match.

Moreover, is there any way I can optimize this regular expression? This regular expression is fairly straightforward but it seems it is complicated.

Thank you.

Comment: in any case, if you do not want to match sub groups, use non-capture grouping: `(?:ABC)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's matching those sub-groups because that's what `()` does. If you want to group items together without matching them to output, use [non-capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:)`. For example: `(?:apple|orange)` would match apple or orange, but would not capture the group to output.

If you want to capture the entire match only without subgroups, do the following:

```
^mango$|^(?:apple|orange)(?:\[(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?\])?$
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dZ1wY6/3)

```js
var strArr = [ 'apple',
'orange',
'apple[]',
'orange[]',
'apple[15]',
'apple[05]',
'mango[]',
'mango' ];

var re = /^mango$|^(?:apple|orange)(?:\[(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?\])?$/;

strArr.forEach(function(str) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str + ' - match? ' + re.test(str) + '<br>');
});
```

Railroad Diagram:

[image]

Comment: Your expression does not capture any matches at all. Needs to be wrapped in a parenthesis.

Comment: @i-- Not true. The entire regex is what matches the use cases. Any sub-grouping is either for matching a sub-group or for substitution.

Comment: Agree, just the question seems to be talking about matching groups, too many of them to be exact, so I mentioned it.

Comment: OPs main concern isn't about matching groups per se, but of the right way of constructing the RegEx for his use case. The matching group thing is more of a realization of OP that the construction with `()` isn't the optimal construction of the RegEx. OP is saying he is getting many groups from `()`, and I have said that what he needs is `(?:)`.

Answer (score 0):

In your regular expression you are declaring (G1|(G2)(G3)).  This is why when you match you get an array with four values:

```
1. apple[15] The whole match
2. apple[15] G1 (mango|(apple|orange)(\[1-9][0-9]*\])?)
3. apple G2 (apple|orange)
4. [15] G3 (\[[1-9][0-9]*\])?
```

If you altered the regular expression to be `/^(mango)|(apple|orange)(\[[1-9][0-9]*\])?$/` you will get the same result, except #2 from above will be undefined unless you have `mango` as the input parameter.  Note that the expression will still accept `mango[123]`, but the match will not include the number.